# Expanding a CardView in RecyclerView expands other CardViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have CardViews in RecyclerView and when I expand a CardView then every tenth CardView from that expanded CardView expands automatically. So if I expand #0 CardView then #10,#20,#30 etc expands too. I am not understanding this behavior.

Comment: *I am not understanding this behavior.* I'm pretty sure that such behavior can be easily explained with your code...

Comment: This is likely because your card views are being reused. The `RecyclerView` does as its name implies and reuses the views it shows as they go offscreen and others come onscreen.

Comment: How can I make it not getting reused?

Comment: *How can I make it not getting reused?* you don't wana do this(`Recycler` part of the class name stands for reusing) 1st it will make your UI slow 2nd you will be not able to restore previously expanded CardViews) ... just store the position of expanded positions somewhere(fx. SparseArray) in adapter and in `onBindViewHolder` expand or collapse CardView

Comment: Code is always usefull.

Comment: @Selvin Could you explain in more details please?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) and take special notice at the way `onBindViewHolder()` works